# Easy question on complex

Tags: complex-numbers

Assume that the Laurent polynomial $f(z)=\sum_{n=k}^{\ell}\alpha_n z^n$ is real on the unit circle $f(e^{i t})=\overline{f(e^{i t})}$.

Why can we deduce that $\ell=-k$ and $\alpha_{-n}=\overline{\alpha_n}$ for all $n$?

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1113854/on-the-proof-of-fej%C3%A9r-riesz-theorem) suggests to differentiate and take $t=0$ but I don't see how it works...

Can I have some help please?

[Screenshot of Barry Simon book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv6de.png)

Comment: So why do you qualify it as "easy" ?

Comment: It appears that question links to [this paper](http://people.virginia.edu/~jlr5m/Papers/FejerRiesz.pdf), which might be worth mentioning.  Additionally, it appears in that papers proof, they assume that $f(e^{it}) = \sum_{k = -n}^{\color{red}{n}} c_k e^{itk}$, so I think they're assuming that in their proof.

Comment: Terrible title...

Comment: Because it seems to be an obvious point in all proof of Fejer-Riesz theorem I read, which is not clear for me, that's all :)

I add a screenshot of such a proof, and they start from $n=k$ to $n=\ell$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

From the definition

$$\sum_{n=k}^{\ell}\alpha_n e^{itn}=\overline{\sum_{n=k}^{\ell}\alpha_n e^{itn}}=\sum_{n=k}^{\ell}\overline{\alpha_n} e^{-itn}=\sum_{n=-\ell}^{-k}\overline{\alpha_{-n}} e^{itn}.$$

Remains to show that all coefficients must coincide, which is obvious by linear independence of the exponentials.